# Simple integrands dense in square integrable integrands

Tags: stochastic-integrals, expected-value, monotone-class-theorem

we defined $\Pi_2=\Pi_2(\{X_t\})$ as the class of predictable processes $\{H_t\}$ such that 
$||H||_x:=(E[\int_0^{\infty}H_s^2d[X]_s]^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty$

and $\mathcal{M}^2$ as the set of all $L^2$ bounded continuous martingales endowed with $||X||_2:=(\text{sup}_{t\geq0}E[X_t^2])^{\frac{1}{2}}$

We first showed that the stochastic integral defined for simple integrands maps a subset of $\Pi_2$ isometrically to $\mathcal{M}^2$.

Now we want to show that this subset is dense in $\Pi_2$. We write this theorem like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlAd5.jpg).

I have some questions to the proof. The proof is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iuhh.jpg) and I marked the points in colours where I'm referring to in the questions.

1. Why is $M^2E[[X^i]_T]\leq M^2 \text{sup}_{t\geq 0} E[(X_t^i)^2]$? ($[X^i]_T$ is the variance process)
2. Why follows $||X||_2 < \infty$?
3. Is this a typo and instead of $f$ it means $0$?
4. Is dropping the finiteness assumption meant in the way that we want our $T$ to be infinitive?

I'm so thankful for your answers!

Comment: Concerning 3.: Yes, you are right. It's a typo and it should be 0 instead of $f$.

Comment: Thanks!! And what do you think about 1?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why is $M^2E[[X^i]_T]\leq M^2 \text{sup}_{t\geq 0} E[(X_t^i)^2]$? ($[X^i]_T$ is the variance process)

By the definition of the quadratic variation (... you call it "variance process"...) we have $$ \mathbb{E}([X]_T^i) = \mathbb{E}((X_T^i)^2)- \mathbb{E}((X_0^i)^2) \leq \mathbb{E}((X_T^i)^2).$$ Hence, in particular, $$ \mathbb{E}([X]_T^i) \leq \sup_{t \geq 0} \mathbb{E}((X_t^i)^2).$$

> 2. Why follows $||X||_2 < \infty$?

It doesn't follow; it's an assumption.

> 3. Is this a typo and instead of $f$ it means $0$?

Yes.

> 4. Is dropping the finiteness assumption meant in the way that we want our $T$ to be infinitive?

No. Until this point the author was assuming that $H$ is bounded (in the sense that $|H(t,\omega)| \leq M$ for some uniform constant $M$). The final step is to extend the result to processes which need not be bounded but which "only" satisfy the assumption of square integrability (see the statement of the theorem).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! To the first point I still have a question:

We defined the variance process for a continuous local martingale as the unique process $[X]_t$ (continuous, predictable and increasing) such that $\{X_t^2-[X]_t\}$ is a local martingale.  How does this equality follow for the expectation?

Comment: @lea5619 Since $X$ is a square integrable martingale, the process $X_t^2 - [X]_t$ is a martingale (and not only a local martingale). Now use that martingales have constant expectation